# How does one wire OV7670 camera with Arduino Due?

Tags: arduino-due

The parts that I want to interface together are:

- Arduino Due
- OV7670 Camera Module
- 3.5" TFT Touchscreen LCD (uses MCUFRIEND_kbv library)

My goal is to get the video feed from the camera to the LCD screen. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I am working with small project same in little bit like what you trying to do..

starting with..
1- Arduino UNO + OV7670 + 2.4" TFT LCD (I got not clear live Image)..

so I made some changes..
2- Arduino DUE + OV7670 Live Image (still working with, having problem in reading Image) want to compile the result Image (convert it to text) then sending the result to (3) by serial Port
3- Arduino UNO + 3.5" TFT LCD (it works)..

by the way  Arduino UNO + OV7670 Live Image (worked perfectly), but I am trying to get same project using DUE.. (faster speed & maybe could deal with Image too..)

here link of how OV7670 work with Arduino DUE..
https://www.instructables.com/How-to-Connect-OV7670-to-Arduino-Due/
.....

Comment: I tried the link you provided (and many others) before coming to stackexchange for help. I wanted to use the OV7670 for sending video feed to 3.5" Touchscreen display. As I was short on time, I did move on to using OV2640 with Arducam chipset as it has libraries available for Arduino Due. So far, the process has been smooth with OV2640 module.